# Codility challenge - why does this solution work?

Tags: c, algorithm, palindrome, anagram

Problem:

Given a string of digits, count the number of subwords (consistent subsequences) that are anagrams of any palindrome.

Example:

For input string "02002" the result should be 11, i.e.:

"0", "2", "0", "0", "2", "00", "020", "200", "002", "2002", "02002"

I can see that solution below works but I cannot understand why. Especially I don't understand the point of the inner loop. Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define M 1000000007
#define COLORS 10
#define SUBSETS (1 << (COLORS))

int solution(char *S) {
    int len, result;
    int *values;
    int v, idx, middle, mask;

    result = 0;
    values = calloc(SUBSETS, sizeof(int));
    //new_values = calloc(SUBSETS, sizeof(int));
    len = strlen(S);
    mask = 0;

    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
        v = S[idx] - '0';
        mask ^= (1 << v);
        values[mask ^ (1 << v)] += 1;
        result = (result + values[mask]) % M;
        for (middle = 0;  middle < COLORS; middle++) {
            result = (result + values[mask ^ (1 << middle)]) % M;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

More details if needed at: https://codility.com/programmers/task/winter_lights/.

Comment: Time to learn how to debug...BTW the only palindrome I can see is  `"2002"`...

Comment: @LPs, I debugged it multiple times but still cannot understand why it works. And read the problem again, it's anagram of a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

For each `idx` you want to count `i` such that the lights from `i` to `idx` can form a palindrome. That means there's an even number of each type of light, or there's an even number of all lights except for one (which sits in the middle of the palindrome).

The code uses a trick to count the `i`, to avoid O(n^2) behavior. After processing the light at index `idx`, the array `values` contains for each `m`, the number of `i<idx` such that the the sequence of lights from 0 to `i` contains even or odd numbers of each light (depending on the bits of `m`). So for example, `values[3]` contains the number of initial sequences of lights (up to `idx` with an odd number of lights 0 and 1, and an even number of the other lights).

With this array, counting the shuffled palindromes ending at `idx` is easy: if the mask up to `idx` is `mask`, then the number of palindromes with an even number of all lights is the same as the number of left-sequences with the same mask (ie: `values[mask]`). Similarly, the number of palindromes with an even number of lights except with an odd number of one light (`middle`) is the same as the number of left-sequences with mask `mask^(1<<middle)`.

Comment: Can you clarify this: So for example, values[3] contains the number of initial sequences of lights (up to idx with an odd number of lights 0 and 1, and an even number of the other lights) ?

Comment: 3 = 0b00000011. Bits 0 and 1 are set.

Comment: I still don't get this part, why is it true: if the mask up to idx is mask, then the number of palindromes with an even number of all lights is the same as the number of left-sequences with the same mask (ie: values[mask])

Comment: Because if lights [0..i] have mask m, and lights [0..idx] have mask m, then lights [i+1...idx] have mask 0. And mask 0 corresponds to the counts of each color of light being even.

Comment: I'll accept your answer even though I still don't get it. Maybe I will in a couple of months :)